# I have to find time taken to register,run vm by euca commands using shell script

Tags: shell, virtual-machine, openstack, eucalyptus

I have to find time taken:

1. To register image (may be found by using time command)
2. Time taken for running (pending to running state).
3. Time to login (may be found by using time command)

I don't know how to find this interval time as I need to check state of VM.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following one-liner to obtain the time taken by an instance to change it's state from pending to running,

```
INS=$( euca-run-instances -k sshlogin -t m1.xlarge emi-F51D3A55 \
| grep INSTA | cut -f 2 ); time while(true); \
do if \[ $( euca-describe-instances $INS | grep INSTANCE \
| cut -f 6 ) = "pending" \]; \
then euca-describe-instances $INS; else break; fi; done
```

This should be reusable for other two as well.

Answer (score 0):

By changing the *rc.local* file, we can make the VM perform some actions just when it becomes *running*. You could possibly save the time instant at which it becomes running in a file inside the VM itself. By this you won't have to keep polling the state of the VM. Once the VM is up, you will have the time instant at which is became *running*.

Hope this helps you out.